# Animation callback executes before finished

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have trouble with executing a function after my animation finishes.

I am making a simple ToDo app and when the user wants to delete a task, I want it to fade away and then call my function which removes it entirely using `setState` in parent component. I have tried researching this myself but to no avail. So the problem is that the task view just disappears instantly instead of waiting for the animation to finish.

```
deletePressed() {
    Animated.timing(
        this.state.fadeIn,
        {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 300,
        }
    ).start(this.props.action());
}
```

*this.props.action*

```
deleteTask(name) {
    const temp = this.state.tasks;
    if (temp.includes(name)) {
        const indx = temp.indexOf(name);
        temp.splice(indx, 1);
        this.setState({ tasks: temp });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving a callback, you are calling the function itself, that's why it gets executed before animation completes. This should work.

```
deletePressed() {
    Animated.timing(
        this.state.fadeIn,
        {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 300,
        }
    ).start(this.props.action);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're not providing a function as a callback to `start()` but sthe result of a function when you do `.start(this.props.action());` so it calls the funtion when defining it.

You should pass it like this : `.start(this.props.action);` or like this `.start(() => this.props.action());` then its the funtion itself that is passed.